# I am interested in drawing the solution for various ODEs and PDEs

Tags: ode

How to draw the solution y=sinx+c for the ODE dy/dx = cosx?
I tried in excel but did not reach a solution.
I am new to this.
Please help

Comment: What did you try? Excel has support for surface plots, so it's definitely doable, although I'd personally prefer something like `python` with `matplotlib`. What do you want to achieve, a plot for a single value of `c` or a surface plot for some range of `x` and `c`? What tools are at your disposal? There are plenty of (basic) tutorials and material on google how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do that in Microsoft Excel, then you can implement, for example, the [Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) for simplicity as follows:

```
B1 cell : initial value of y, for example, 0
B3 cell : initial value of x, for example, 0
B4 cell : step size, for example, 0.1, which should be sufficiently small

D1 cell : =$B$2
E1 cell : =$B$1

D2 cell : =D1+$B$3
E2 cell : =E1+COS(D1)*$B$3
```

Next, select the D2 cell and copy it to D3, D4, ... by dragging the fill handle, up to the point that you want to get. Then, select the E2 cell and copy it to E3, E4, ... by double-clicking the fill handle. This gives (x, y) data in D and E columns, and you can make a plot with them. The above initial values correspond to `c=0` in your equation.
[image]